# How to get week based on the date in java?

Tags: java, date

I need to display week's start date. While selecting this week(28-12-2015), i am getting "29-12-2014" as start date because it is calculating based on week and year. Today's(28-12-2015) week i am getting as 1st week. I need to get last week of the year with the date as "27-12-2015" as start date.

Here is my code:

```
public Date getStartDate() 
    {

            int weekNo = findWeekOfTheYear(new Date());
            int year = findYear();
            startDate = findStartDateUsingWeekAndYear(year, weekNo);        

             return startDate;
    }

public int findYear()
     {   
         Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

          int year= calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

         return year;
     }

public int findWeekOfTheYear(Date date)
     {
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.setTime(date);

          int weekOfMonth= calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

         return weekOfMonth;
     }

public Date findStartDateUsingWeekAndYear(int year,int week)
     {

         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.clear();
         calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
         calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

         // Now get the first day of week.
         Date date = calendar.getTime();

         return date;
     }
```

Any help?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What is your input, what is the expected output, what does it give instead? Please give additional examples that are not exactly at the end of the year, if you think the end of the year may be an issue here.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Input is today's date.By keeping this input date, i need to get the week. For ex: Today is 28-12-2015.I am expecting week as 53 but i am getting 1.

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. This topic has been addressed many times already.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
public Date findStartDateUsingWeekAndYear(int year,int week)
     {

     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

     calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
     calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year+1);
     calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
     calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
     calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
     // Now get the first day of week.
     Date date = calendar.getTime();

     return date;
 }
```

But if you want to get first day of current week, use

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
```

instead of

```
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
```

Comment: i am getting start date as "27-Dec-2016" instead of "27-Dec-2015"

Comment: i told you, set `calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year+1);`

Comment: i have added you code. Because of "calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year+1);" next years date is showing